# How to emit and recieve whitout a Authenticated using socketio-jwt

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, jwt

My Sockets work fine when a client has the token (provided by Laravel jwt) but, a need to work with the clients while they aren't authenticated yet, I Want something like:

```
io.sockets
.on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  timeout: 15000 // 15 seconds to send the authentication message
}))

.on('authenticated', function(socket) {
  console.log('Authenticated!!');
  // This works:
  socket.on('setDataRegistered', function(datos) {
    console.log('Registering!');
  });
})
// This doesn't works:
.on('config', function(socket) {
  console.log('A client wants to be configured before authenticated!');
})
```

How can I call from the FrontEnd to 'config' (socket.emit('config')) before authenticate??

Thanks for your help. Sorry my English.

Comment: Helloooo, can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // Client connected but not authenticated. Client has to emit to 'authenticate' for authentication

        socket.on('authenticate', function (data, fn) {
            // Authenticate socket.

            // define more events
        });

        // still accessible to unauthorised sockets
        socket.on("other-event", function(data) {

        });
});
```

I don't use any middleware for authentication. But that's just me. I never found the use for it.

Comment: I was thinking that. But how do I validate the jwt socket in the 'authenticate' function? That's what the middleware does for me. So, how do I do it manually? Thank you!

Comment: I use Laravel to validate and create the token. Later, I send that token to nodejs.

Comment: @bluesky777 You just decode the token. Check your library's docs.

Comment: @bluesky777 glad i could help

Comment: I spent two hours trying to figure out why my client wasn't sending an emit to the server. Turns out I was using `io.on` rather than `socket.on`, but the server need to check for the event using `socket`. Make sure you're using socket if you're running into a similar issue!